# TSP optimization using K-means recursively in python: clusters connections problem

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, k-means, traveling-salesman

I code a python script to get a solution for the TSP using clustering (K-means). The principle is to create clusters and get the optimal path between each clusters (using their centroids). Then, for each cluster:

- if the number of cities inside is inferior to a treshold -> get the optimal path between cities
  -else -> get sub-clusters inside the current cluster and repeat steps...
  At the end, it returns a list of cities that must be an optimal path.
  To calculate optimal path between clusters (and cities), it use a brut force method that returns the best path.
  My problem is when it connects clusters: For some clusters, it is not the optimal connection, while it calculates the first and last sub-clusters (or cities) by their distance to the (last city) of the previous cluster and their distance to the next cluster (its centroid).
  I don't understand why I have (sometimes) long (and obiously not optimal) connection paths between clusters. So the question is:
  Why do there are some big connection paths and how to reduce them ?

Here is the code:

```
#Solve a traveling salesman problem using K-means clustering recursively
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import itertools, math, random, sys, openpyxl, time

start_time = time.time()

NB_CLUSTERS = 6
TRESHOLD = 8

# Class to represent a city
class City:

    def __init__(self, coordinates, name= None):
        # Coordinates of the city
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        if name==None:
            self.name = f"City_{self.coordinates[0]}{self.coordinates[1]}"
        else:
            self.name = name

    def showTime(self):
        print(f"City name: {self.name}, coordinates: ({self.coordinates[0]}, {self.coordinates[1]})")


# Class to represent a cluster (geographic area)
class Area(City):

    def __init__(self, coordinates, cities = None,  nbClusters = NB_CLUSTERS, isEarth = False):
        # Coordinates of the area (mean of all cities in the area)
        super().__init__(coordinates)
        # List of cities in the area
        if cities == None:
            self.citiesList = []
        else:
            self.citiesList = cities
        # List of (sub)areas in the area
        self.areasList = []
        # number of sub-areas in the area
        self.nbMAreas = nbClusters
        # Is earth .
        self.isEarth = isEarth
        if self.isEarth:
            # next cluster
            self.nextCluster = self.citiesList[0]
            self.nextClusterCoordinates = self.citiesList[0].coordinates
            # previous cluster
            self.previousCluster = self.citiesList[0]
            self.previousClusterCoordinates = self.citiesList[0].coordinates
        else:
            # Set during the execution
            # next cluster
            self.nextCluster = None
            self.nextClusterCoordinates = [0, 0]
            # previous cluster
            self.previousCluster = None
            self.previousClusterCoordinates = [0, 0]
        
        # Frist sub-area
        self.firstSubCluster = None
        # Last sub-area
        self.lastSubCluster = None
        

    def addCities(self, cities):
        self.citiesList.extend(cities)

    def setNextClusters(self, nextC):
        self.nextCluster = nextC
        self.nextClusterCoordinates = nextC.coordinates

    def setPreviousClusters(self, previousC):
        self.previousCluster = previousC
        self.previousClusterCoordinates = previousC.coordinates
    
    # From the cities in the area, get clusters (sub-areas)
    # Add cities to their sub-areas
    # Get the first and last clusters
    # Sort clusters
    # Output: self.areasList = list of sub-areas (sorted)
    def getClusters(self):
        data = []
        # Check if there are enough cities to cluster
        #if len(self.citiesList) >= TRESHOLD:
        # Add coordinates of all cities in the area to the data
        for city in self.citiesList:
            data.append([city.coordinates[0], city.coordinates[1]])

        # Cluster the data
        self.kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=self.nbMAreas)
        self.kmeans.fit(data)

        # Add each cluster to areasList
        for center in self.kmeans.cluster_centers_:
            self.areasList.append(Area( coordinates = center, nbClusters=self.nbMAreas))

        # Add cities to each cluster
        for i, label in enumerate(self.kmeans.labels_):
            self.areasList[label].addCities([self.citiesList[i]])

        # Remove empty clusters
        self.areasList = list(filter(lambda x: len(x.citiesList) > 0, self.areasList))

        # Sort clusters to get the minimum distance between clusters
        self.getPerfectPath()

        # get first and last sub-cluster
        self.getFirstAndLastSubCluster()

        # set sub-clusters neighbours
        for i in range(len(self.areasList)):
            nextClustIndex = i+1
            if nextClustIndex == len(self.areasList):
                self.areasList[i].setNextClusters(self.nextCluster)
            else:
                self.areasList[i].setNextClusters(self.areasList[nextClustIndex])
            previousClustIndex = i-1
            if previousClustIndex == -1:
                self.areasList[i].setPreviousClusters(self.previousCluster)
            else:
                self.areasList[i].setPreviousClusters(self.areasList[previousClustIndex])

    # Get the perfect path between points (cities or clusters)
    # First sub-cluster is firstSubCluster
    # Last sub-cluster is lastSubCluster
    # Output: self.areasList = list of sub-areas (sorted)
    # Use permutations
    def getPerfectPath(self, cluster = True):
        # Get the list of sub-areas without the first and last sub-areas
        if cluster: localList = self.areasList
        else: localList = self.citiesList
        # Remove the first and last sub-areas
        minDistance = 999999999999999
        # Get previous point = lastClusterCoordinate from previous cluster
        if self.isEarth == True:
            previousPoint = self.previousCluster
        else:
            try:
                previousPoint = self.previousCluster.lastSubCluster
            except:
                previousPoint = self.previousCluster
        # Get next point = next cluster coordinate
        nextPoint = self.nextCluster
        # Get for all pemrutations
        for permutation in itertools.permutations(localList):
            permutation = list(permutation)
            # Calculate the total ditance
            permutation.insert(0, previousPoint)
            permutation.append(nextPoint)
            distance = self.distanceFullPath(permutation)
            if distance < minDistance:
                minDistance = distance
                if cluster:
                    self.areasList = permutation[1:-1]
                else:
                    self.citiesList = permutation[1:-1]
    @staticmethod
    def distanceFullPath(myClusters):
        distance = 0
        for i in range(len(myClusters) - 1):
            distance += math.dist(myClusters[i].coordinates, myClusters[i+1].coordinates)
        return distance

    # Function returning the optimal path (cities) --> function call by user
    def getOptimalPath(self):
        listOfCities = []
        # Check if there are enough cities in cluster
        if len(self.citiesList) >= TRESHOLD:
            # Get sub-clusters
            self.getClusters()
            # for each sub-cluster, get the optimal path
            for area in self.areasList:
                listOfCities.extend(area.getOptimalPath())
            if self.isEarth:
               # Add the first city at the end (to close the path)
                listOfCities.append(listOfCities[0])
            return listOfCities
        # If not enough cities, return the perfect path between cities in the area
        else:
            self.perfectCitiesPath()
            return self.citiesList

    def perfectCitiesPath(self):
        # Check if there are not too many cities in cluster
        if len(self.citiesList) < TRESHOLD:
            # Sort clusters to get the minimum distance between clusters
            self.getPerfectPath(False)
            # Get first and last cities
            self.getFirstAndLastSubCluster(False)
        else:
            print("ERROR: Too many cities")


    def getFirstAndLastSubCluster(self, clusters=True):
        if clusters:
            self.firstSubCluster = self.areasList[0]
            self.lastSubCluster = self.areasList[-1]
        else:
            self.firstSubCluster = self.citiesList[0]
            self.lastSubCluster = self.citiesList[-1]

    def showTime(self):
        print(f"Cluster name: {self.name}, coordinates: ({self.coordinates[0]}, {self.coordinates[1]})")
        # Print the list of cities in the cluster
        for city in self.citiesList:
            city.showTime()

    # Display the area
    def displayArea(self, solution = False, showInfo = True):
        x = []
        y = []
        for city in self.citiesList:
            x.append(city.coordinates[0])
            y.append(city.coordinates[1])
        # True if clusters have been solved
        if solution:
            try:
                # Plot cities with clusters colors
                plt.scatter(x, y, c=self.kmeans.labels_)
            except:
                print("Please solve the problem first")
        # False if clusters have not been solved
        else:
            # Plot cities without clusters colors
            plt.scatter(x, y)
        if showInfo:
            # add annotations for each point
            for city in self.citiesList:
                plt.annotate(f'{city.name}({city.coordinates[0]},{city.coordinates[1]})', xy=(city.coordinates[0], city.coordinates[1]), textcoords='offset points', xytext=(0, 10), ha='center')
        plt.show()
        
def displayConnectedCities(citiesList, plot = True):
    # Check if the list is not empty
    if not citiesList:
        print("The cities list is empty.")
        return

    # Extract coordinates and names for plotting and annotation
    x_coords = [city.coordinates[0] for city in citiesList]
    y_coords = [city.coordinates[1] for city in citiesList]
    names = [city.name for city in citiesList]

    # Plot cities
    #plt.scatter(x_coords, y_coords)
    # Connect cities
    plt.plot(x_coords, y_coords, marker='')  # Connects in order
    """
    # Annotate each city
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        plt.annotate(name, (x_coords[i], y_coords[i]))
    """
    # Display the graph
    if plot:
        plt.show()

def importData(filePath):
    data = []
    with open(filePath) as fp:
        line = fp.readline()
        while line:
            data.append(line)
            line = fp.readline()
    # Delete 7 first first lines
    data = data[7:-1]
    # from "A BBBB.BBB CCCC.CCC" to [BBBB.BBB, CCCC.CCC]
    for line in range(len(data)):
        strline = data[line].split(" ")
        data[line] = [float(strline[2][:-2]), float(strline[1])]
    return data

def main():

    # averageDistance = []
    # # Make iterations
    # for i in range(10):
    #     earth = Area([0,0], cities = cities_2, isEarth = True)
    #     optimal_path = earth.getOptimalPath()
    #     optimal_path.append(optimal_path[0])
    #     print("-----------------------")
    #     print("Nb of clusters: X") #, earth.nbMAreas)
    #     print("Original path distance:", Area.distanceFullPath(cities_2))
    #     print("Optimal path distance:", Area.distanceFullPath(optimal_path))
    #     print("-----------------------")
    #     displayConnectedCities(optimal_path)
    #     averageDistance.append(Area.distanceFullPath(optimal_path))
    # averageDistance = sum(averageDistance) / len(averageDistance)
    # print("Average distance:", averageDistance)
    # plt.show()

    global TRESHOLD
    # Clear logs.txt
    logfile = open('mylogs.txt', 'w')
    #logfile.write('')
    #logfile.save()
    # close it
    logfile.close()
    # Redirect sys.stdout to the file
    stdout_fileno = sys.stdout

    # Parameters variation
    # NB of clusters: from 7 to 10
    # Threshold: from NB of clusters to 12
    # NB of cities : from 10 to 1000 (100 by 100)
    it = 0
    # list of cities keeping same cities through all iterations
    all_cities = []
    for i in range(1000):
        all_cities.append(City([random.randint(0,100), random.randint(0,100)]))

    #Check length --> if it's not 1000, add more cities
    while len(list(dict.fromkeys(all_cities))) != len(all_cities):
        # Remove duplicates
        all_cities = list(dict.fromkeys(all_cities))
        for i in range(1000 - len(all_cities)):
            all_cities.append(City([random.randint(0,100), random.randint(0,100)]))

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('results.xlsx')
    sheet = wb['Feuil1'] 
    sheet.delete_rows(2, 100000)

    print("Start")
    for nbClusters in range(6,8):
        for threshold in range(nbClusters+1, 9):
            TRESHOLD = threshold
            # Select the nbCities first cities
            my_cities = all_cities
            earth = Area([0,0], cities = my_cities, isEarth = True, nbClusters = nbClusters)
            optimal_path = earth.getOptimalPath()
            sys.stdout = open('myLogs.txt', 'a')
            print("-----------------------")
            print("Nb of clusters:", nbClusters)
            print("Threshold:", threshold)
            print("Nb of cities:", len(my_cities))
            print("Original path distance:", Area.distanceFullPath(my_cities))
            print("Optimal path distance:", Area.distanceFullPath(optimal_path))
            print("-----------------------")
            sys.stdout = stdout_fileno
            it += 1
            print("iteration:", it)
            # Write in excel sheet the results
            sheet.append([nbClusters, threshold, len(my_cities), Area.distanceFullPath(my_cities), Area.distanceFullPath(optimal_path), Area.distanceFullPath(optimal_path) / Area.distanceFullPath(my_cities)])
            wb.save('results.xlsx')

            #displayConnectedCities(optimal_path)

def main_base():
    # list of cities (FIXED)
    Paris = City([0,5], name = "Paris")
    London = City([10,2], name = "London")
    Berlin = City([8,10], name = "Berlin")
    Milan = City([7,10], name = "Milan")
    Rio = City([3,5], name = "Rio")
    Sydney = City([5,4], name = "Sydney")
    Moscow = City([12,5], name = "Moscow")
    Seoul = City([1,6], name = "Seoul")
    Tokyo = City([1,5], name = "Tokyo")
    NewYork = City([5,8], name = "NewYork")
    cities_1 = [Paris, London, Berlin, Milan, Rio, Sydney, Moscow, Seoul, Tokyo, NewYork]

    # list of cities 
    cities_2 = []
    for i in range(10000):
        cities_2.append(City([random.randint(0,100), random.randint(0,100)]))
    
    #Check length --> if it's not 1000, add more cities
    while len(list(dict.fromkeys(cities_2))) != len(cities_2):
        # Remove duplicates
        cities_2 = list(dict.fromkeys(cities_2))
        for i in range(1000 - len(cities_2)):
            cities_2.append(City([random.randint(0,100), random.randint(0,100)]))
    

    cities_3 = []
    data = importData("ch71009.txt")
    for i in range(len(data)):
        cities_3.append(City(data[i]))
    earth = Area([0,0], cities = cities_2, isEarth = True)
    optimal_path = earth.getOptimalPath()
    print("distance:", Area.distanceFullPath(optimal_path))
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    displayConnectedCities(optimal_path)

def main_several():
    # list of cities 
    cities_2 = []
    for i in range(1000):
        cities_2.append(City([random.randint(0,100), random.randint(0,100)]))

    #Check length --> if it's not 1000, add more cities
    while len(list(dict.fromkeys(cities_2))) != len(cities_2):
        # Remove duplicates
        cities_2 = list(dict.fromkeys(cities_2))
        for i in range(1000 - len(cities_2)):
            cities_2.append(City([random.randint(0,100), random.randint(0,100)]))

    ITERATION = 100
    for i in range(ITERATION):
        earth = Area([0,0], cities = cities_2, isEarth = True)
        optimal_path = earth.getOptimalPath()
        displayConnectedCities(optimal_path, plot=False)
        print("Iteration", i)
        print("Optimal path distance:", Area.distanceFullPath(optimal_path))
    plt.show()


def getOptiPaths(cities, nbClusters = 6, treshold = 8, nbIterations = 10):
    pathList = []
    global TRESHOLD
    global NB_CLUSTERS
    TRESHOLD = treshold
    NB_CLUSTERS = nbClusters
    print("Start")
    for i in range(nbIterations):
        print("Iteration", i)
        earth = Area([0,0], cities = cities, isEarth = True)
        optimal_path = earth.getOptimalPath()
        pathList.extend([optimal_path])
    print("End")
    return pathList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Number of processes to create
    main_base()
```

NEW CODE -> Handle large number of random cities

It generates random cities in main_base(), you can use cities from a .TSP file form here [text](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/countries.html) or use fix cities (cities_1).
Here is some examples of long paths [2 examples of aberrant long paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MePi2.png)

Comment: Why do I have big connection paths and how to reduce them ?

Comment: After investigation, it seems that I cannot be sure the long paths are connection paths: they could be paths inside a cluster, connecting 2 cities. However, I have difficulties to undesrtand why, using this algorithm, I can have very long paths like these althrough a cluster must contain a small number of cities (TRESHOLD), and these cities are supposed to closed to each other. If someone have any idea...

Comment: it is not clear what the question actually is...